# How to block list of users?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a home task and not able to understand this requirement.It basically wants me to :

> On start-up allow a list of blocked users to be provided. If the user
>   is blocked, registration should fail with correct http status code.

Does this mean I need to implement an new endpoint (because its not mentioned). The only thing mentioned is I needed to have one endpoint, `/create` which is to create the user, or is it that I have to maintain a list of usernames in a static block and then match the incoming name with the list, if it contains, fail the request for that ?

I want to know if I have understood the problem correctly and if not then how would an experienced guy develop this requirement.

PS.

I cannot ask for clarifications from the question provider !!

Comment: What kind of Data Source do you use?

Comment: I am using an in memory database

Comment: Still unclear...Maybe add the whole requirement...*On start-up allow a list of blocked users to be provided*. I would never create a server that will wait any kind of input on startup (well i've done this but **configs should be real configs** and **data should be stored within the datastore**.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions say that "on start-up allow a list of blocked users to be provided." That suggests that the list should be passed in.

You could pass a system property like this:

```
java -Dmyproject.blocked=user1,user2,user3 my project.Startup
```

The retrieve it using `System.getProperty`, split it using comma as a delimiter, and build a `Set` of blocked users that you can query when handling a request.

If you're using Tomcat then I think you can pass in settings using the environment variable `JAVA_OPTS`. Bash lets you set an environment variable and run a command all in one go:

```
$ JAVA_OPTS=-Dmyproject.blocked=user1,user2 /path/to/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start
```

It's also possible that the instructor means that you should store the blocked users in a database table (assuming you have a database) and just *read* the list at startup. In this case you should hook the reading of the database table into the initialization of your app. How you do this depends on the technology. If you are using servlets, then you could use the `init` method. Spring Boot probably has its own way to identify a class to run at startup.

Comment: Yes I am using springboot and h2 as in memory DB. But the thing is if it is blocked user it should not be saved only. This is what is confusing me.

Comment: Your list of blocked users is separate from whatever other information you are saving about the users. The person running your server provides the list of blocked users.

Comment: Yeah. So basically I need to create a separate table which will maintain the blocked users. If I have a record there, then validate it against the incoming request and do the needful. I understood. Thanks Wilis !